# Proguard leads to crash

Tags: android, android-proguard

When setting

> minifyEnabled true
>
> useProguard true

in my gradle I get a NullPointerException like this :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller/com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller.LoginActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Gradle is :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

While reading through StackOverflow I found some settings for the proguard-rules.pro file like this:

```
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -verbose
    
    
    -dontoptimize
    -dontpreverify
    
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
    -keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
    -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
    
    # For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native ;
    }
    
    # keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
    # see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
    -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
       void set*(***);
       *** get*();
    }
    
    # We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
    -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
       public void *(android.view.View);
    }
    
    # For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }
    
    -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
    }
    
    -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
        public static ;
    }
    
    -dontwarn android.support.**
    
    # Understand the @Keep support annotation.
    -keep class android.support.annotation.Keep
    
    -keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}
    
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        @android.support.annotation.Keep ;
    }
    
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        @android.support.annotation.Keep ;
    }
    
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        @android.support.annotation.Keep (...);
    }
```

When I disbale minifyEnabled everthing works fine.
Thancks

Comment: and what is in your proguard file?

Comment: yes, send it ? @MatiasOlocco

Comment: show proguard file and full gradle.build file

Comment: @handerianous I'm asking you to include your proguard file, otherwise we cannot know what is wrong with it.

Comment: remove useProgaurd true from bauild.gradle file its unnecessary, and post complete build.gradle file.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco i want put proguard file but stackoverFlow don't allow

Comment: @handerianous you could open the file and copy the content... as you did with the code. Check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in Proguard

```
-keep class com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller.LoginActivity**
```

But this will cause the Proguard to ignore the LoginActivity class, and your code will not be obfuscation.

The best way is to see which element has caused this creation to be introduced to the Proguard.

Comment: Although this is true, he didn't post the file yet, this will enable the LoginActivity, but not the rest...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your proguard file yet, but I'm quite sure that adding this:

```
-keep class com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller.** { *; }
```

Will solve the problem.

Some docs [in here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Taking the proguard file that you added, it should be:

```
-keep class com.jafari.farhad.ubazdidcontroller.** { *; }
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose


-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native ;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
void set*(***);
*** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static ;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@android.support.annotation.Keep ;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@android.support.annotation.Keep ;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@android.support.annotation.Keep (...);
}
```

Comment: thanks you for answer matias but this package is Important and i want proguard it :)

Comment: Have you a standard proguard file  ?

Comment: ok, just add the line I put in my answer at the end of your proguard file.

Comment: @handerianous I put your proguardfile updated in my answer with the line I suggest

Comment: ,ubazdidcontroller is important package and don't should keep it

Comment: Please, read the documentation, if you dont want to read the documentation, try what I suggest, I'm trying to help you and you are ignoring what I say. That is your apps package, adding that to the proguard file makes it to STAY, not to LEAVE.